# Pass generic using function.apply in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I'm coding a personal project (I first started the project as Javascript) where some http requests have to be made. To do that, I decided to use Axios. So, I created a file named http.js with the following content.

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const baseURL = '/api';

const requestWrapper = async (request, { url, options, data }) => {
  const config = { baseURL, ...options };

  const requestObject = await request.apply(
    this,
    data ? [url, data, config] : [url, config]
  );
  const requestData = requestObject.data;

  return { status: requestObject.status, data: requestData };
};

const get = async (url, options) => {
  try {
    return await requestWrapper(axios.get, { url, options });
  } catch (error) {
    return error.response;
  }
};

const remove = async (url, options) => {
  try {
    return await requestWrapper(axios.delete, { url, options });
  } catch (error) {
    return error.response;
  }
};

const post = async (url, data, options) => {
  try {
    return await requestWrapper(axios.post, { url, data, options });
  } catch (error) {
    return error.response;
  }
};

const put = async (url, data, options) => {
  try {
    return await requestWrapper(axios.put, { url, data, options });
  } catch (error) {
    return error.response;
  }
};

const patch = async (url, data, options) => {
  try {
    return await requestWrapper(axios.patch, { url, data, options });
  } catch (error) {
    return error.response;
  }
};

export { get, remove, post, put, patch };
```

What I did in the last code snippet is encapsulate each http request into a function named similarly. This was done to make easier the code in case the http client library (Axios) were changed.

The thing is that now I want to convert this file to **Typescript**. The specific problem I have, is that in the previous code I made a wrapper function because the calls for each http function are very similar, this wrapper function should receive a generic T to pass it through the Axios function in order to type the response. However, I don't know how to pass this generic because in the following function:

```js
const requestWrapper = async (request, { url, options, data }) => {
  const config = { baseURL, ...options };

  const requestObject = await request.apply(
    this,
    data ? [url, data, config] : [url, config]
  );
  const requestData = requestObject.data;

  return { status: requestObject.status, data: requestData };
};
```

Specifically:

```js
 const requestObject = await request.apply(
    this,
    data ? [url, data, config] : [url, config]
  );
```

I don't know a way where i can specify the generic. What should I do?

I searched but didn't find something specific like my problem. I have thought to remove the internal wrapper and call each Axios function inside its specific encapsulation function.

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] including the typings you're using? Right now all we have is your JS code so in order to begin to help I'd need to clear up lots of errors, most of which are probably unrelated to your issue (presumably `url` is just a `string` everywhere), and the issue you're actually having with generics isn't present, since there is no `T` defined anywhere.  If you do decide to [edit] your code to be a [mre] and want me to take another look, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Function#apply` is weakly typed, you're gonna have to use a type cast if you want a stronger type:

```
    const requestObject = await (request.apply(
        this,
        data ? [url, data, config] : [url, config]
    ) as ReturnType<typeof request<T>>)
```

Full code:

```
const requestWrapper = async <T>(request:
    typeof axios.get |
    typeof axios.post |
    typeof axios.put |
    typeof axios.patch |
    typeof axios.delete
    , { url, options, data }) => {
    const config = { baseURL, ...options };

    const requestObject = await (request.apply(
        this,
        data ? [url, data, config] : [url, config]
    ) as ReturnType<typeof request<T>>)
    const requestData = requestObject.data;

    return { status: requestObject.status, data: requestData };
};
```